# Prevent commits in master branch

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

(For simplicity) I have a `master` branch and a `dev` in my Git repository. I want to ensure the `master` branch is always working, so all work I do should be in the `dev` branch.

However, when I merge my changes in with a `--no-ff` merge, I tend to stay in the `master` branch, and just continue working in it (because I forget to checkout my `dev` branch).

Can I put up a rule for the `master` branch, which states I can't do commits, and fast-forward merges, but only `--no-ff` merges from another branch?

This must work for private hosted repositories (ergo, not GitHub or Bitbucket).

Comment: "fast-forward commits" is not a thing. Commits are just commits, `git commit` makes a new one, there is no fast-forwarding happening. It sounds like you just want to prohibit ordinary commits when the current branch is `master`, in which case, look into the `pre-commit` hook.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You must create a pre-commit hook which rejects commits to the master branch. Git doesn't call a pre-commit hook when you call the *merge* command, so this hook will be rejecting only regular commits.

1. Go to your repository.
2. Create a file, *.git/hooks/pre-commit*, with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

   if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
     echo "You can't commit directly to master branch"
     exit 1
   fi
   ```
3. Make it executable (not required on *Windows*):

   ```
   chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
   ```

To disable *fast-forward* merges, you must also add the following option to your *.git/config* file:

```
[branch "master"]
    mergeoptions = --no-ff
```

If you want also protect the master branch on your remote, check this answer: *[How to restrict access to master branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864405/how-to-restrict-access-to-master-branch-in-git)*

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need - does this work in Windows as well?

Comment: @RasmusBækgaard yes it will: the bash script for the hook will be interpreted by the Git bash included in Git for Windows. (You just don't need the chmod step)

Comment: note: you can also prevent yourself from pushing to a remote `master` branch in the pre-push hook. ex: https://gist.github.com/aaronhoffman/ffbfd36928f9336be2436cffe39feaec

Comment: Nice, for anyone looking for a way to add these rules or other git hooks in the project repository, check this simple npm package: https://github.com/kilianc/shared-git-hooks, because you can't include anything that resides under the .git directory into the repository.

Comment: Instead of making one my teammates (or my own) day harder when we accidentally make changes to master and then try to commit, and then get rejected, is there any way to tell Git to create a warning when it sees  any changes in master?

Comment: also, this is only for our local git repo, how can we enforce rules across different git repos for all developers without having them manually change the contents of .git directory?

Comment: This should only work for one user right? Ideally this rule should apply to the whole repo

Comment: Note to those new to bash scripting (like myself): the space between the square brackets and double quotes in the if line are **required**. I found that out the hard way... glad I figured it out eventually. Took me a few minutes though. ;)

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly, except when there are merge conflicts and need to commit the merge result, there's any way to allow this?

Comment: found `-n` "This option bypasses the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks."

Comment: Hey, @qzb could we make that a global pre-commit hook? So that we always will have that same filw when we initialize a new git repository?

Answer (score 50):

You can use the [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) utility to do this. It has a built-in `no-commit-to-branch` hook that can be used to prevent commits to one or more branches.

### Setup

The basic setup process is:

- Install using [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) or [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (instructions at https://pre-commit.com/#install)
- Create a `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file in the root of your project (see below for a first draft)
- Install the hooks into your Git configuration by running `pre-commit install`.

### Basic configuration for protecting branches

Here is a basic configuration that includes just the `no-commit-to-branch` hook:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
  rev: v3.3.0
  hooks:
    - id: no-commit-to-branch
      args: ['--branch', 'master']
```

If you want to protect multiple branches, you can use include multiple `--branch` arguments in the argument list:

```yaml
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks
  rev: v3.3.0
  hooks:
    - id: no-commit-to-branch
      args: ['--branch', 'master', '--branch', 'staging']
```

### Isn't this all overkill?

Pre-commit has many other [built-in hooks, and a large collection of community-built hooks](https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html) that will transform the way you clean up and validate your commits. The reason I mention this is because, while this tool may be overkill for just preventing commits to a protected branch, it has many other features that make it a compelling and simple addition to any Git project.

Comment: Super useful! I will definitely try this out, thanks for the information @JGC

Comment: Thank you, a nice suggestion! Note that `main` and `master` are covered by default if there is no `--branch`.

Answer (score 20):

It may make sense to install it globally via

```
git config --global core.hooksPath ~/githooks
```

and moving that `pre-commit` file into that directory

Comment: What if I have multiple repositories - won't it affect all of them?

Comment: and that is what you may what to do in most of the cases

Comment: Say I have this weird project, where they renamed ``master`` to ``Production`` - can exceptions be made?

Comment: you can use or operator in bash to specify more branches you want to protect on client side

Comment: Install what globally? Can you [make it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58500870/edit) clearer in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I guess he meant to install the pre-commit hook globally for all local git repositories, since the .git folder lies inside each repo's folder. With the suggested action, there will be a global "githooks" folder, under user's home folder, where he/she can put the same pre-commit hook script and it will be active for commits to any repo.