# Disable local commits in a branch

Tags: git

I want to know if there's an option to disable committing to a local branch. I forget sometimes to open a new branch when developing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Why would you not commit to a local branch?

Comment: We have a branch in the server that no one pushes too. My problem is that you can commit to the local branch. I want to diaable that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hooks you can install which get executed before a commit. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462111/git-prevent-commits-in-master-branch).

Also if you have already written code and realize you're on the wrong branch you could `git stash` the changes.

Comment: I tried doing git stash but it weirdly put some unknown files in my commit. Maybe I did something wrong. Are the hooks going to work on a commit to a local branch?

Comment: Well what else do you want to commit to other than a local branch?

Comment: I want a branch that the only action you can do on it is pull. It's the dev branch that everytime a branch gets approved it upload it to the dev branch. So the only thinf I want permitted on the dev branch is pull.

Comment: That should be possible with a pre-commit hook. https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Also you could manually alias all git commands to execute a script instead.

Comment: Awesome. I'll try it out. Thanks.