# How to use "git merge --squash" while preventing regular commits using git hooks

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

I would like to prevent commits to master using a local commit hook as per the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465455/329496

That works fine as I can now merge changes on feature branches into master:

`git merge feature_branch`

I actually want to use squash merges so that finished features land as a single commit on master:

`git merge --squash feature_branch`

That doesn't actually merge it creates the squashed changes as modified files in my index. I then have to commit those index changes yet I have disabled commits to master.

Is there a way to prevent commits to master and also ensure work merged from feature branches is squashed automatically?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, Git doesn't know the difference between a commit on `master` that is of the kind you want (a merge squash) and the kind you don't want (everything else).   There really isn't a way to do this with plain Git, although various hosting platforms (e.g. GitHub and GitLab) offer this as an option for pull requests.

However, there is a workaround.  You can create another branch (say, `master-merge`) by running `git checkout -B master-merge master` and perform the squash there, then fast-forward to `master` by using `git merge --ff-only master-merge` while on `master`.  Then no actual commits are made on `master`, only fast forwards.