# Why wont my pre-commit hook run when i commit

Tags: git, github

[image]

[image]

I have this code below in my Github Repository, i want to prevent anyone in my repo from committing directly to master, but it isnt working, what a, i doping wrong?

[image]

I have searched through stack overflow and youtube trying to find tutorials for this issue and i havent had any luck

```
9 lines (6 sloc)  154 Bytes
#!/bin/sh

branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
  echo "You can't commit directly to master branch"
  exit 1
fi
```

I want users to be blocked from committing directly to master
Currently they are able to commit to master

My script is definitely execute-able, but still it doesnt display anything

Comment: Did you set the executable flag?

Comment: I attempted to that that, but im not sure exactly what to do, would you be able to tell me?

Comment: `chmod +x <FILE>`

Comment: I have tried that, but it is still not working @SergioTulentsev.

Comment: Are we positive that your file is named `pre-commit` (no extension) and is in directory `.git/hooks` ?

Comment: Yes i am sure, file path is "(RepoName)/hooks/pre-commit"

Comment: @MurrackCarn: that's a wrong path

Comment: What do you mean? And also can you explain how the file path would effect this hook? The file is definitely executeable

Comment: @RomainValeri: it doesn't match one in Romain's comment.

Comment: the .git part of the file path disappears once you type it in, but i did enter it

Comment: Does it? Interesting. Well, in any case, this is how it should work. You must be deviating _somewhere_, but we don't yet see where.

Comment: Ill attach some screenshots of relevant information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462111/git-prevent-commits-in-master-branch

Comment: Thank you Sergio, i saw that thread but it doesnt work for me, same with all other threads that i have seen

Comment: So your file IS in `hooks/`, not `.git/hooks`. That's your problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is correct, the location is the problem. And just to forestall your next question, no, there is no easy way to share such hooks with all team-members, each of them will have to place that hook into their `.git/hooks` folder. You can write a script that puts it there, but each team-member must execute that.

Comment: In addition to your hook you might want to configure github with branch protection rules so that even if someone commits on master locally, they will not be able to push those commits to github. You can even configure it to then require a pull request to get commits onto master. This is more important than your local hooks precisely because it's not something each team member can opt out of.

Comment: I've summed up most of the useful points from the comments in a community wiki answer, everyone feel free to contribute of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a hook to be **locally executed**, be sure to have your hook in a `pre-commit` file in `.git/hooks`

It will work for *this* particular repo, but should be introduced in each involved repo where you want this to be effective.

---

In addition to your hook you might want to configure github with branch protection rules so that even if someone commits on master locally, they will not be able to push those commits to github. You can even configure it to then require a pull request to get commits onto master. This is more important than your local hooks precisely because it's not something each team member can opt out of.