# How to prevent direct commits to master branch using husky?

Tags: git, git-husky

I am using husky to run git hooks.

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
```

I want to prevent direct commits to master branch. It should allow the master branch to be updated only by merge requests.

I came across following code from [Git: Prevent commits in master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462111/git-prevent-commits-in-master-branc). I copied this to .git/hooks/pre-commit and it works

```
#!/bin/sh

branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
  echo "You can't commit directly to master branch"
  exit 1
fi
```

But I want to achieve this using husky. How do I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created a file with the content provided from OP.

file: hooks/pre-commit

```
#!/bin/sh

branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
  echo "You can't commit directly to master branch"
  exit 1
fi
```

Then I added an entry to husky pre-commit field in package.json

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "sh hooks/pre-commit",
    }
```

No more commits to master :)

Answer (score 3):

With [git-branch-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-branch-is) you can block commits with husky in master branch

```
"pre-commit": "git-branch-is -r \"^((?!master).)*$\""
```

Comment: there is a `--not` since https://github.com/kevinoid/git-branch-is/pull/29

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's the right place to make this restriction because it can easily be bypassed.
As an alternative, I would recommend you to modify the protection rules of the repository/branch.

Here is how it's done with GitHub and Bitbucket:

- GitHub: https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/enabling-branch-restrictions
- Bitbucket: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html

I know it's a different approach but I hope it's helpful too.

Comment: As a side note, It can't prevent pushing from admin