# Prevent accidental direct edit or commit on git main branch

Tags: git, workflow

Since I am still learning, sometimes when I'm using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) I just forget and edit / commit a file directly to main.

I don't like having to roll the change back and re-commit on a non-main git branch.  I don't want to rebase or merge my main branch into development prematurely.

Is there something I can configure in my [git](https://github.com/git/git) client so it will stop me before I make a direct edit or commit to main?  FYI, this is a occupational problem that may be foreign to some; in my job, git / vim / python are intimately woven together in this tapestry and I cannot expect everyone to get all the nuances of the relationships.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent commits in master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462111/prevent-commits-in-master-branch)

Comment: See the `pre-commit` hook at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64060996/7976758 . You can use it directly, without `husky`. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Prevent+commit+branch+hook

Comment: There's nothing wrong with working on the wrong branch _locally_.... once you realize that's the case, just take corrective measures. If you created a feature branch and did not switch to it, then you can place the feature branch in the current position (`git branch -f teature-branch`) and then go back to where the current branch should be (say it's 2 commits behind: `git reset --hard HEAD~2`). It's not like you _won't_ be doing those operations ever.... those are 2 of the very basics of git that you will eventually do from muscle memory, if you ask me. (**careful** with `git reset --hard`).

Comment: Please do not add "comments" in your post. They do not belong there and will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something I can configure in my git client so it will stop me before I make a direct commit to main?

I am not sure about configuring a git client to do that; as one alternative you can wrap vim with a script such that it checks the git branch before editing.

[image: warn on git main]

I wrote a `vim` wrapper in python to do the checks for you.

#### python wrapper to check for edit git main

Save this and make it executable; `/usr/bin/env` is native to Linux and WSL... I'm not sure about running it native to a Windows filesystem.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import run
import locale
import shutil
import shlex
import sys
import os


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKCYAN = '\033[96m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    RED = '\033[91m'
    RED_FLASH = '\033[5;37;91m'
    RED_REVERSE = '\033[0;37;41m'
    RED_FLASH_REVERSE = '\033[5;37;41m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


class _GetchUnix:

    def __call__(self):
        import termios
        import tty
        import sys
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch


class _GetchWindows:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self):
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch()


class Getchar:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            import msvcrt
            msvcrt.LK_LOCK
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self):
        return self.impl()


class cd:
    """Context manager for changing the current working directory"""
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = os.path.expanduser(newPath)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)


getchar = Getchar()


def find_git_branch(directory):
    """cd into a directory and return the git branch that it's on"""
    with cd(directory):
        enc_str = locale.getpreferredencoding()
        proc = run(shlex.split("git status"), capture_output=True)
        try:
            git_branch_list = proc.stdout.decode(enc_str).splitlines()[0].split()[2:]
            git_branch = ' '.join(git_branch_list).strip()
        except IndexError:
            git_branch = ""
        return git_branch


def check_git_edit(directory, vi_command):
    """if a file is on a git master branch, ask before editing it"""
    # check the git branch of the directory...
    git_branch = find_git_branch(directory)
    if git_branch == "main" or git_branch == "master":
        print(f"{bcolors.RED_FLASH_REVERSE}You are editing on git {git_branch}, are you sure? (Y/N){bcolors.ENDC}")
        user_input = getchar()
        if user_input.upper() == "Y":
            # Run vim.basic which allows ~/.vimrc... vim.tiny does not!
            run(shlex.split(vi_command))
    else:
        run(shlex.split(vi_command))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if shutil.which("vim") and not shutil.which("vim.basic"):
        vim = "vim"
    elif shutil.which("vim.basic"):
        vim = "vim.basic"
    else:
        raise OSError("vim is not installed")
    vi_command = f"{vim} {' '.join(sys.argv[1:])}"
    filepath = os.path.expanduser(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
    dir_part = os.path.split(filepath)[0]
    if dir_part != "":
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filepath)
        check_git_edit(dirname, vi_command)
    else:
        check_git_edit(os.getcwd(), vi_command)
```

Comment: Stopping an edit on git main is even better than stopping a git commit to main

Answer (score 3):

I also recommend you adopt the habit of work in different branches where you include new features or fix buggs. If you are working in a very small project maybe it's not necessary use other branches besides main, in that case you can make all you changes directly

Based on your question:

> Is there something I can configure in my git client so it will stop me before I make a direct commit to main?

Yes, you can configure Git to add an extra layer of protection before allowing direct commits to the main branch. One common approach is to use Git hooks, specifically the pre-commit hook, to enforce certain checks before allowing a commit.

Here's a simple example using a pre-commit hook:

1. Navigate to your Git repository in the command line.
2. Go to the .git/hooks directory. If you don't find a pre-commit file, create one.
3. Open or create the pre-commit file and add the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prevent direct commits to the main branch
if [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "main" ]; then
    echo "Direct commits to main are not allowed. Please use feature branches." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Save the file and make it executable:

`chmod +x pre-commit`

Then whenever you try to make a commit directly to the main branch, the script will prevent it and display an error message.

Comment: re: `maybe it's not necessary use other branches besides main, in that case you can make all you changes directly`.  *No, I have to merge a separate development branch into main before commiting to our corporate main branch.  This is a company policy, I am not going to fight with my manager about this*