# How to remove remotes/origin/master after move to main?

Tags: git

The project we are using had its `master` branch moved to `main`, on GitLab for reasons of consistency.

Locally I had renamed the master branch to main:

```
git branch -m master main
```

This seemed to be enough until I accidentally did `git checkout master` and then it recreated the master branch. Doing a `git branch -a`, I see I now have the following two remotes (in addition to my other ones):

```
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/master
```

How do a tell the local repo to forget about `remotes/origin/master`, to avoid accidentally recreating `master`, when I mean to switch to the `main` branch?

Comment: See `git fetch --prune`. By default, `git fetch` reads the names from the other (remote) Git and creates or updates your local `origin/*` names to match. So you *had* `origin/master`. Then you renamed `master` over there, and now your Git sees `main` and creates and updates `origin/main` and ... leaves the old stale `origin/master` in place because nobody said to delete anything, now did they?

Comment: The `--prune` option, which I do think should be the default but one must be slightly careful with it, means *if you don't see it over there, remove it over here*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step would be to try:

`git fetch --prune`

If that does *not* work, it could mean the master branch is still on GitLab remote repository side (it could have been pushed by mistake by another developer who also checkout the wrong local `master` branch first)

In any case, once GitLab repository is clean, you can also add a [pre-commit hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60762137/6309) in order to prevent any future accidental checkout of the wrong branch.