# Can I configure universal pre-commit hooks for my machine?

Tags: git, pre-commit.com

I am interested in adopting the [pre-commit framework](https://pre-commit.com). I would like to create hooks for common errors that I tend make. For example, I want to:

- [stop myself committing to a branch named "main" or "master"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60762137/236081) even in projects that have not (yet) adopted pre-commit
- use the correct Git persona (personal vs work) when committing
- confirm I have made a signed commit even in projects that have not (yet) adopted pre-commit or signing conventions
- ...and more

These hooks are likely *not* appropriate for inclusion in project-specific repos, so they should not be stored in `$PROJECT/.pre-commit-config.yaml`. Additionally, I don't want to have to copy them into every single repo I clone.

Is there a local location (in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME maybe?) for a "universal" `.pre-commit-config.yaml`?

(Ideally the solution should be compatible with projects that *do* define their own pre-commit config.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why "not committing to master / main" wouldn't be appropriate in the repo config though -- it's one of the more popular [out of the box hooks](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks#no-commit-to-branch)

there is intentionally not a supported path for what you want -- **the intent of `pre-commit` is that the exact linting tools are versioned along with the repository** so everything is kept consistent for all contributors

that said, you can add a legacy hook which calls pre-commit with your custom hooks

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec pre-commit run --config ~/.config/pre-commit/config.yaml`
```

put that at `.git/hooks/pre-commit.legacy` (or make it part of your `init.templateDir` similar to what's [written about here](https://pre-commit.com/#automatically-enabling-pre-commit-on-repositories))

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: thank you! I've elaborated on my use cases for clarity, but I understand now that this is outside the scope of precommit