# Search for a keyword within a GitHub wiki

Tags: github, wiki

I would like to search for any mentions of a specific keyword on a GitHub wiki.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: GitHub web app use questions are better for http://WebApps.StackExchange.com (but this is too old to migrate)

Comment: I found it safer to [clone my private repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080848/how-do-i-clone-a-github-wiki?rq=1) and use my IDE for searching.

Comment: Since Aug 8 2016, Github provides this feature in its search bar. See screenshot in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633277/728675)

Comment: Since Oct. 2021, GitHub wikis are actually searchable with Google or other search index services! See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542007/6309)

Comment: Actually, they are *not* searchable yet. But GitHub/Microsoft is actively looking at making them searchable. Again, I have edited [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542007/6309) accordingly with the latest details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

March 2023, from [issue 4992](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/4992#discussioncomment-5335353):

- https://github-wiki-see.page/ offers a way to index wiki for search, pending GitHub resolution.
- GitHub wiki pages are now being indexed for wiki with Above 500 stars, with "`Editing Restricted to Repository Collaborators`" turned on

---

2012:

I don't know of a native GitHub search which would support that.

I usually use a Google search, like in this example where I search for **[VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510046/gitolite-update-hook-exclude-a-repository/11517112#11517112)** in the Gitolite documentation pages: https://www.google.com/search?q=vref+site%3Agitolite.com%2Fgitolite%2F

I use the "`site:`" search selector to limit the search to a particular subdomain (like the wiki) of a web site:

```
vref site:user.github.io/aRepo/
```

But that won't work for wiki (still true in Oct. 2021).

I find it easier to do a local search by cloning said wiki:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/yourRepo.wiki
```

(Take the name of your repo, and add a "`.wiki`" to access the git repo associated with said wiki).

---

Update Oct. 2021: a Google search will still not work for GitHub wiki pages!
See [this discussion](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4992#discussioncomment-1439485) and [`github/docs` PR 10836](https://github.com/github/docs/pull/10836)

[Daniel Adams](https://github.com/dipree) (Program Manager @microsoft & @github) adds:

> We have intentionally excluded `Disallow: /*/wiki*` from the `robots.txt`.
>
> **However, we have also introduced an `x-robots-tag: none` in the http response header of Wiki pages**.
> **As a result, Wikis are still not visible to search engine crawlers**.
>
> Why have we done this?
>
> Abusive behavior in Wikis had a negative impact on our search engine ranking and therefore we had to exclude Wikis from getting crawled to mitigate the effects.
> We are now investigating options how we can open the gates again so that everyone can benefit from the great information documented in Wikis.
> At this point, we have not decided on whether or when we will allow Wikis to be crawled again, but we are actively reviewing this and will keep you posted with any updates.

---

Jan. 2022: [`github/feedback` discussion 4992](https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/4992): "Permit search engines to index Github wikis" suggests:

> The current criteria does appear to be "**Restrict Editing to Collaborators Only**", and some sort of user/organization aggregated star total.
>
> That said, there are odd stragglers left out here and there that don't meet the aggregated star requirement so I don't know what's going on there.
> About 1.2k wikis meet this rough criteria out of ~400k.
>
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_W9s8IhnSoypXjTKYSRBK5CNPTQJfXRl7V_1mY0Xq28/edit#gid=905984022
>
> Awesome! It's a start but hopefully GitHub will expand the list.

Comment: @ShawnSouth I agree. I have edited the answer to propose an alternative solution to this search issue.

Comment: (Deleted and re-added b/c I wasn't allowed to edit.) There are a couple of things that are problematic with the original answer: 1) The format subdomain.github.com redirects to subdomain.github.io - which is the Pages hosting - which is not where the repository wiki lives. 2) Google site: searches don't appear to work for subfolders. Ex: github.com/BellevueCollege/BellevueCollege.github.io/wiki

Answer (score 15):

You can install the [GitHub Wiki Search](https://github.com/linyows/github-wiki-search) user script in your browser.

Comment: That plugin no longer seems to work, unfortunately

Comment: This extension is working fine for me now.

Another solution is to `git clone` the wiki and use `grep` and other tools on your local machine to search.

Comment: It's working for me on Firefox via GreaseMonkey: http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/129930