# Is there a way to search github wiki pages?

Tags: github

I added a [wiki page](https://github.com/avidanyum/spray-tomcat-example/wiki) to a github repository
but when I do a search in github for a sample text from it `"this is a very nice wiki page can we search it"` no results are found, instead, I get `We couldn't find any repositories matching 'this is a very nice wiki page can we search it'`.  Is there a way to tell github that this wiki page should be searchable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535602/search-for-a-keyword-within-a-github-wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't any way to use GitHub's built in search feature for Wiki pages. I guess it may be something they add in the future.

You can use the [GitHub Wiki Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-wiki-search/gdifdhnjmjaidbajhapmbcbnoocoeooc) Chrome plugin to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 13):

There is a built-in search feature, [since Aug 8, 2016](https://blog.github.com/2016-08-08-search-wiki-pages/). It is in the same search bar at the top of any of your project's github pages.

[image: demo]