# Proactively keeping a git repository small

Tags: git, large-files

I was about to commit some media files to a git repository, but then I stopped because I was put off by the huge file size of these files. These files are expected to be obsolete in the future, so I want to avoid polluting the git history with these huge objects. 
At that point, I don't mind that the history of these media files gets lost.

I've looked around and found many suggestions that use `git-filter-branch`. This method requires rewriting the git history, which I want to avoid because it requires attention from other developers on my team.

Now I'm considering to create a submodule within the main repository which contains the media files. Then, whenever the submodule gets too unwieldy, I can either purge the history or use [`git replace` as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470780/is-it-possible-to-slim-a-git-repository-without-rewriting-history) to reduce the size of a (fresh) checkout.

Is this method sane? If not, what would be the best way to allow for the possibility to remove a git object's data from the history in the future?

What I basically want (which is not possible due to Git's design of commit integrity) is:

```
AAAA = 1kb                AAAA = 1kb
BBBB = 100MB         -->  (somehow get rid of BBBB's data)
CCCC = 3kb                CCCC = 3kb
= 100MB checkout size     =  4kb checkout size
```

Comment: Is your environment such that you can have a shared mount to the large files?

Comment: @AndrewC Yes. This git repository is used by the development and deployment teams. It's important that the deployment team gets the latest version of the media files.

Comment: You could include a script into the repository, e.g. `fetch-media-files.sh` that just fetches the current media files from a server or a shared drive and places them into the working directory.

Comment: It's not ideal, but we've used a separate repository (completely separate, not a submodule) that was NFSed mounted to each developer machine and always available and then symlinked out to that from the main repo.