# Github enforce --no-ff when merging

Tags: git, github, merge

Is is possible to enforce merges with the `--no-ff` flag for git repositories on Github?

I need to keep the history with the extra merge commit, but I'm not sure if the Github merge UI will do this?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083724/can-i-enforce-a-merge-only-branch-in-git

Comment: @AnishShah Possibly? But this question is about Github specifically, not git in general. My config options, hooks, etc.. might be limited

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add an alias to your gitconfig file:

```
[alias]
    fmg = merge --no-ff
```

Then when you want to perform a merge, simply use your new alias as so:

```
git fmg <branch-to-merge>
```